# javascript populate div with information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to populate a div after 3 select boxs are selected, but simply nothing happens. I know the php function works since I tested it manually but can't do it to populate automatically.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catcol").change(function(){ 
        getSubCat();//get sub category after change event

    });
    $("#scatcol").change(function(){ 
        getSubSubCat(); //get sub category after change event

    });
    getSubCat();//get sub category after page load
    getSubSubCat();
    TestF();
    function getSubCat(){
        var selectedCategory = $("#catcol option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "collection_scat.php",
            data: { category : selectedCategory } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#scatcol").html(data);
            getSubSubCat();

        });
    }
    function getSubSubCat(){
        var selectedSubCategory = $("#scatcol option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "collection_sscat.php",
            data: { subcategory : selectedSubCategory } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#sscatcol").html(data);

        });
    }
    function TestF(){
    var cat = document.getElementById("catcol").value;
    var scat = document.getElementById("scatcol").value;
    var sscat = document.getElementById("sscatcol").value;
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'collection_list.php',
    data:'cat='+cat+'&scat='+scat+'&sscat='+sscat,
    success:function(msg){
         $("#list").html(data);
    }
    });
    }

});
```

The Select Box populates great, but the list doesnt populate.
Also, as the code is, if I access other pages in my project they don't load. Only page where the code is used works.

Anyone could help me checking the problema with my code?

Comment: What is the data being returned from the ajax calls?

Comment: You might want to include your HTML as well, and get a snippet working:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: Your question says "3 checkboxes", but your code looks like it is looking for the `selected option` from 3 different `<select>` elements.

Comment: I've corrected my grammar. Sorry it's my bad English. @Sanchit Patiyal I've got it. I'm trying list data value instead of msg value. Now it's working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `$("#list").html(data);` to `$("#list").html(msg);`

Comment: I've commented above I found the error and that's right as your answer :). But now I have a footer file that includes all the JS code. If I'm not in the page that uses that code it throw errors. How can I handle this?

Comment: You can do this by setting a flag as 1 and 0 in php. If the js is required for that page, then set the flag to 1 on that otherwise set it to 0 and simply include the js code in the if-else block checking that flag.